# Does ASP.NET close streams automatically upon navigating to a different page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

If my web application is in the middle of reading a large file, and the user navigates to a different page, what happens to the execution of the previous page? Does it complete, or is the page and the open file steam flushed and closed?

Comment: depends on how you navigate, take this for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx you can choose to keep executing the response

Comment: You may get an exception that the client close the connection, and the thread will be terminate.

Comment: Note that ASP.NET knows nothing about whether the client has navigated to a new page. As the answers below indicate, it _will_ know if the connection has been closed, but only when it tries to write to the output stream.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, your page will continue to process the file until it's time to write the output to the client, at which time it will abort.

What kind of app is it?  Windows Forms?  MVC?  The app won't know the client is no longer there until it has to write to the stream.

Comment: MVC. The function is run in a SignalR hub.

Comment: @arao6 - well, i'm not familiar enough with SignalR to know how it handles disconnects, but chances are it's going to keep running until either the thread times out, or you write to the response.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Erik.
Once you have submitted the request, it will process it and then when its time to write to the output client, it will abort it.

Comment: Please make it clear that the request will only abort if the client has disconnected.